# No Role found with id: 106 (HTTP 404) in Keyrock when creating new application

Tags: fiware

I have a problem when creating new application in Horizon(Identity manager GE).
Im logged in as idm user and when creating application, on the first step when i specify name, description, callback and url and press next i get following error:

```
Error: No Role found with id: 106 (HTTP 404)
Error: Unable to register the application.
```

[image: Image:No Role found with id: 106]

What might be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake was in the Horizons local_settings.py file.
instead of attributes FIWARE_PURCHASER_ROLE_ID and FIWARE_PROVIDER_ROLE_ID pointing to corresponding row ids of table role_fiware like this:

```
FIWARE_PURCHASER_ROLE_ID = '5786623590bc4f3ab01c61733a13ee6d'
FIWARE_PROVIDER_ROLE_ID = '4806909eb4b646c7a1f11ad9f9ed53ed'
```

attributes were :

```
FIWARE_PURCHASER_ROLE_ID = '106'
FIWARE_PROVIDER_ROLE_ID = '191'
```

I guess that is default configuration for sqlite db.
So if using mysql db just insert correct ids in this file for these attributes from table role_fiware.